# Modded minecraft LAN world never appears

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-forge

I am wanting to play a modpack with a friend of mine on the same wifi network using LAN but in the multiplayer section of the client player, it never shows that host players world. I have tried many things to fix this but nothing worked. Anything that could help?

Comment: Are you sure you're both using the same mods and settings? Same Minecraft and mod versions?

Comment: @twobugs Yes.  We both downloaded the exact same modpack within minutes of each other and started a new world and opened to LAN but unable to connect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding the server manually using his IP and Port information (fixed it for me, even when using hamachi). Furthermore some people say it helps to be in the same home network (windows settings).

Additionally you should check that neither java nor minecraft are blocked by firewalls.